# How to clear unknown injector error for factory in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to AngularJs.
while injecting factory we are getting unknown provider error. For form posting i refered this[Ben Nadal](http://www.bennadel.com/?site-photo=638)

Version: AngularJs 1.5.5

Below my controller and factory. Can anyone help me to reolve.

```js
//Factory
angular.module('transformRequestService', [])
.factory('transformRequestAsFormAsPost',
function () {
// I prepare the request data for the form post.
function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {
var headers = getHeaders();
headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
return (serializeData(data));
}
// Return the factory value.
return (transformRequest);
// ---

function serializeData(data) {
// If this is not an object, defer to native stringification.
if (!angular.isObject(data)) {
return ((data == null) ? "" : data.toString());
}
var buffer = [];
// Serialize each key in the object.
for (var name in data) {
if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
continue;
}
var value = data[name];
buffer.push(
encodeURIComponent(name) +
"=" +
encodeURIComponent((value == null) ? "" : value)
);
}
// Serialize the buffer and clean it up for transportation.
var source = buffer
.join("&")
.replace(/%20/g, "+")
;
return (source);
}
});


//App.js
var routerApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'
, 'vendorLoginModule'
, 'ui.bootstrap'
, 'createUser'
, 'ui.grid'
, 'ui.grid.selection'
, 'ui.grid.exporter'
, 'ngLoadingSpinner'
, 'confirm'
, 'transformRequestService'
]);


//injecting in controller
angular.module('confirm', [])

.controller('confirmController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$uibModal', '$log', '$state', '$filter', '$crypthmac', '$rootScope', '$sce', 'transformRequestAsFormAsPost ', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $uibModal, $log, $state, $filter, $crypthmac, $rootScope, $sce, transformRequestAsFormAsPost) {
------

}
```

Answer (score 0):

]

is missing in your controller

Comment: sorry. '[' missed while copying from actual code.i cannot use this factory in any controller

Answer (score 0):

You have your `transformRequestAsFormAsPost` factory registered on the module `transformRequestService`, but you don't lay that module as a dependency for your module where you use the factory, so you cannot use its services and factories.

Do this instead:

```
// laying a dependency on 'transformRequestService' module
// results in the ability to use its services and factories
angular.module('confirm', ["transformRequestService"]);
```